# Apache Camel is listening same message continuously from IBM MQ queue

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, ibm-mq

I'm trying to pick up a message from IBM MQ queue and place it to my local ActiveMQ using XML DSL. The routing is working, but it picks up the same message continously and placing to ActiveMQ. It seems it falls into a never ending process. I have to shut down the process to stop it. Why is it so?

This is how the bean is defined in `camel-conetxt.xml`:

```xml
<route id="get">
    <from uri="websphere:queue:CU_CUPO705_REP" />
    <log message="GOT MESSAGE with Body ${in.body}" />
    <inOnly uri="activemq:queue:MyOutputQueue" />
</route>

<bean id="websphereConnectionFactory"
    class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="*****" />
    <property name="port" value="****" />
    <property name="queueManager" value="****" />
    <property name="channel" value="****" />
    <property name="transportType" value="1" />
    <property name="shareConvAllowed" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="websphereConfig"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory"
        ref="websphereConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
     <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER" />
</bean>

<bean id="websphere"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="websphereConfig" />
</bean>
```

Output -

```
2020-07-15 10:21:41.278  INFO 5212 --- [CU_CUPO705_REP]] get: GOT MESSAGE with Body <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><API><Header><Function></Function><Author></Author><Version></Version><CreateTime></CreateTime><ClientStartTime></ClientStartTime><ClientEndTime></ClientEndTime><BrokerStartTime></BrokerStartTime><BrokerEndTime></BrokerEndTime><BackendStartTime>2020-07-15-10.21.41.238</BackendStartTime><BackendEndTime>2020-07-15-10.21.41.239</BackendEndTime><ReplyStatus></ReplyStatus></Header><GKSReply><ReplyBody><address><HouseKey>96325874</HouseKey><Municipality>100</Municipality><ZIP>8900</ZIP><Street>1234</Street><Street>test</Street><HouseNo>3</HouseNo><Letter></Letter><Locality></Locality></address></ReplyBody><ReplyStatus>OK</ReplyStatus></GKSReply></API> 
2020-07-15 10:21:41.415  INFO 5212 --- [CU_CUPO705_REP]] get: GOT MESSAGE with Body <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><API><Header><Function></Function><Author></Author><Version></Version><CreateTime></CreateTime><ClientStartTime></ClientStartTime><ClientEndTime></ClientEndTime><BrokerStartTime></BrokerStartTime><BrokerEndTime></BrokerEndTime><BackendStartTime>2020-07-15-10.21.41.238</BackendStartTime><BackendEndTime>2020-07-15-10.21.41.239</BackendEndTime><ReplyStatus></ReplyStatus></Header><GKSReply><ReplyBody><address><HouseKey>96325874</HouseKey><Municipality>100</Municipality><ZIP>8900</ZIP><Street>1234</Street><Street>test</Street><HouseNo>3</HouseNo><Letter></Letter><Locality></Locality></address></ReplyBody><ReplyStatus>OK</ReplyStatus></GKSReply></API> 
2020-07-15 10:21:41.467  INFO 5212 --- [CU_CUPO705_REP]] get: GOT MESSAGE with Body <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><API><Header><Function></Function><Author></Author><Version></Version><CreateTime></CreateTime><ClientStartTime></ClientStartTime><ClientEndTime></ClientEndTime><BrokerStartTime></BrokerStartTime><BrokerEndTime></BrokerEndTime><BackendStartTime>2020-07-15-10.21.41.238</BackendStartTime><BackendEndTime>2020-07-15-10.21.41.239</BackendEndTime><ReplyStatus></ReplyStatus></Header><GKSReply><ReplyBody><address><HouseKey>96325874</HouseKey><Municipality>100</Municipality><ZIP>8900</ZIP><Street>1234</Street><Street>test</Street><HouseNo>3</HouseNo><Letter></Letter><Locality></Locality></address></ReplyBody><ReplyStatus>OK</ReplyStatus></GKSReply></API>
```

The purpose is to print the output log only once.

Comment: How is the IBM MQ JMS session setup?

Comment: @JoshMc question updated with camel-context.xml.

Comment: Try `websphere:queue:CU_CUPO705_REP?transacted=true`

Comment: @Bedla Thanks. It has improved the situation. Now it's not falling into infinite loop. The current situation is that it's picking up the same message three times. So whenever a new message in the IBM MQ queue, the listener picks up it three times and sends all of those to Activemq.

Comment: Is there any way we can send the ACK to IBM MQ after picking up the message? It seems that my code is not doing that.

Comment: After picking up the message, we still see the message in the IBM MQ queue. How can we ensure the message gets deleted once we pick it up?

Comment: @Amit it sounds like the message is being delivered to your listener code, but something in the listener logic is causing the message to rollback. Can you share your listener code and check for any other error messages that might be useful. There is no need to ACK receipt of the message, it's a property of the get call and successful completion of your transaction.